# Wrong Image displayed by Facebook Open Graph

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

All my webpage has open graph meta tags including "og:image" and it points to correct image url. But when I share any post it shows wrong image.

I used url debugger tool from facebook it shows og:url link to some other image. But if I click on "Fetch new Information" button then it shows correct image.

Is there any solutions to this problem. I really need help.

Note: I use jetpack Photon and jetpack sharing tool too.

Thanks for any suggestions.

example url : http://news.sanil.com.np/%E0%A4%AB%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B2%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%95%E0%A4%BE-%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE/

or any link from "news.sanil.com.np"

Comment: I saw that when you use the URL debugger, it shows your websites logo in the story on fb for every url. Just a thought can you try removing the option og:image tags like width & height. I don't think that might be necessary for this.

Comment: its removed, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: as of now I see in the fb url debugger its showing the same image as you're setting in the og:image params. I think its resolved.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your function.php

```
function fb_home_image( $tags ) {
    if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) {
        // Remove the default blank image added by Jetpack
        unset( $tags['og:image'] );

        $fb_home_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'large');
        $tags['og:image'] = esc_url( $fb_home_img );
    }
    return $tags;
}
add_filter( 'jetpack_open_graph_tags', 'fb_home_image' );
```